# sqllite3.dll issues with UWP app development for Mobile

Tags: sqlite, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am trying to learn how to develop apps for UWP for both Desktop and Mobile.  I have been currently working on getting the Entity Framework working in my app to store application state and followed the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started

It worked well for Desktop, the issue however is that when I try to run it on the Windows Mobile emulator I get the following error in debug mode when the code reaches the db.Database.Migrate() step:

```
Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found
```

In the link I pasted above, someone else had the same issue and in the comments they recommended to try the following:

```
Step 1: Install SQLite VSIX pacakge for Universal Windows Platform development using Visual Studio 2015
https://www.sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-uwp-3130000.vsix

Step 2: Install NuGet package SQLite.NET-PCL
Install-Package SQLite.NET-PCL

Step 3: Add references
Add Reference -> Universal Windows ->Extensions -> Make sure the following packages have been checked: "SQLite for Universal Windows Platform" "Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platform Apps"
After that, if you get the error "Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'sqlite3.dll', do the following:
copy sqlite3.dll from 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UAP\v0.8.0.0\ExtensionSDKs\SQLite.UAP.2015\3.8.11.1\Redist\Debug\ARM\sqlite3.dll
past to (override it)
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.nuget\packages\SQLitePCL.raw_basic\0.7.1\build\native\sqlite3_dynamic\winrt81\arm\sqlite3.dll
```

The problem after doing those steps is that I am now seeing the issue when doing a build for "Payload contains two or more files" however not in the SQLitePCL.raw_basic directory (I don't even seem that have that).  Instead my error is the following:

```
Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'sqlite3.dll'. Source files: 
C:\Users\admin\.nuget\packages\SQLite\3.13.0\runtimes\win7-x86\native\sqlite3.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UAP\v0.8.0.0\ExtensionSDKs\SQLite.UWP.2015\3.13.0\Redist\Debug\x86\sqlite3.dll
```

I have been searching everywhere and am truly stumped as to how to get my UWP program working on Mobile.  Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you got the solution for resolving the exception `The specified module could not be found`  from @Leandro_Medeiros_Machado 's comment on [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started).  If you got the `Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'sqlite3.dll'` exception after you done the above three steps you may be also found the next solution from the  comment.

> After that, if you get the error "Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'sqlite3.dll', do the following:copy sqlite3.dll from
>   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UAP\v0.8.0.0\ExtensionSDKs\SQLite.UAP.2015\3.8.11.1\Redist\Debug\ARM\sqlite3.dll`
>   past to (override it)
>   `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.nuget\packages\SQLitePCL.raw_basic\0.7.1\build\native\sqlite3_dynamic\winrt81\arm\sqlite3.dll`

For you, you may need to copy from 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UAP\v0.8.0.0\ExtensionSDKs\SQLite.UWP.2015\3.13.0\Redist\Debug\x86\sqlite3.dll` to(override) `C:\Users\admin\.nuget\packages\SQLite\3.13.0\runtimes\win7-x86\native\sqlite3.dll`.

But actually, for using EF core you don't need the above steps and I recommend you check your environment instead of using the above workaround. I created a simple EF project by following the document and without install the VSIX I can run successfully on the emulator (build 10586). My VS build is 2015 update 3, my OS version is build 14393 and the EF core version is [`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 1.1.0`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite/). So please firstly check if your environment met the following requirements:

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2015 Update 3
- The latest version of [Windows 10 Developer Tools](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads)

And if your EF core and EF core tools versions are right.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.  I definitely have everything upto date since I just recently installed everything from the Microsoft website.  I have Windows 10 build 14393, Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 1.1.0.  I tried to overwrite the file anyway, but the message still remains.  My EF Core Tools version is 1.1.0-preview4-final.  I should also mention that I am running it on the Mobile emulator build 14393 if that makes a difference.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Copying it over to the mentioned directory seemed to have done the trick, which wasn't working before I had created this Question ironically.  Maybe I just needed to restart my machine.  However I do have everything current and am not able to get it to work without adding the VSIX and following those steps.  I was trying on the 14393 Mobile emulator.  Any ideas why that would be?  All the other versions are the same as yours.

Comment: @sikhness, I also test on emulator build 14393 it can work well. Please also check if the .NetCore version is 5.2.2. And it seems like your issue is more like an emulator issue, may be re-download the emulator may resolve.  Any way now you resolved with a workaround. If my reply helped you could you please mark as accepted?